# Injective function from the set $\{0,1,\ldots,2^n-1\}$ to the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n!\}$

Tags: functions

Is there an injective function from the set $\{0,1,\ldots,2^n-1\}$ to the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n!\}$ such that the numbers in the first set are "well" distributed on the second set?

For example one could take $m \rightarrow \left \lfloor \frac{m}{2^n-1} \cdot n! \right \rfloor$. Then the numbers of the left set would be nicely distributed on the right set, but this function is not injective since the floor function is not.

Comment: You haven't made clear what kind of mapping is called for, except that you want an injective mapping (only possible if $n \ge 4$).  "Well" distributed or nicely distributed can be interpreted in several ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight change will work:
$$
m\mapsto\Bigl\lfloor\frac{n!}{2^n-1}\Bigr\rfloor\,m\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks! That's what I missed!